# NetBeans using maven project will not step through the code when attaching to a jvm in another application

Tags: java, maven, debugging, netbeans

My first time using NetBeans with Maven.  Everything works great from within NetBeans.  Can build, package install, etc.  Can debug and step through code.  The problem starts when I attempt to debug my code by attaching to another application which links a JVM instance instead of debugging within NetBeans.

I am attaching to a process using shared memory transport and it succeeds.  When I call from that process a java method with a breakpoint, it breaks.  I can inspect variables and I can tell that it stopped in the right place, but it refuses to step through the code.  NetBeans does not highlite in green the line where it stopped and stepping through the code leads netbeans into some Java bowels popping up Integer class, HashMap class, etc. and complaining that no source code is available.  I can however set another breakpoint in my code and hit continue.  It will stop there, but again will not step.

My speculation is that it has something to do with maven and incomplete debug information in my class files.  If I reconfigure my project to use ant everything works correctly, but going back to maven screws it up again.

The Debugging view in NetBeans shows "Hidden Source Calls":

[image]

Anybody has any thoughts? Thanks

I am starting my application with linked jvm.dll with the following options:

-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_shmem,address=myexecutable,server=y,suspend=n

Here are my sample pom files:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.some.company.edited</groupId>
<artifactId>atpg-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.1</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Parent Project</name>

<properties>
    <!-- Build Metadata -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <!-- App & Platform Versions -->
    <java.target.version>1.7</java.target.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <!-- Build Plugin Versions -->
    <maven.compiler.plugin>3.2</maven.compiler.plugin>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>atpg-main</module>
    <module>atpg-dm</module>
</modules>

<!-- Dependency VERSIONS -->
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<!-- Shared Dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <!-- Test Dependencies (can't hurt to include these all the time) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin}</version>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.target.version}</source>
                <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.some.company.edited</groupId>
    <artifactId>atpg-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>atpg-main</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Main Project</name>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Project module dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>atpg-dm</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.some.company.edited</groupId>
    <artifactId>atpg-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>atpg-dm</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Exchange Format Data Model</name>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <version>0.13.1</version>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. Resolution was extremely simple. Turns out that with Maven projects created outside of the NetBeans environment one has to open not only the parent project, but also all the modules in the project. Due to my ignorance, I did not do that.  I only opened the parent project.

In the open project dialog there is actually a check box "Open Required Projects:" and it was off.  Once I checked it, my parent opened with all modules as separate projects and everything works beautifully well.

So, the problem had nothing to do with incomplete debug information in Java class files.  It was just a NetBeans peculiarity that this check box is off by default.